# How many digits including after decimal point can NUMBER(x) hold?

Tags: plsql, sqldatatypes

For plsql data type NUMBER(x) is want to know the maximum number of digits after the decimal place it can hold (assuming i am using only 1 digit before decimal point) . Is there some rule by which this can be derived .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits001.htm#i287903):

> **NUMBER**
>
> 999...(38 9's) x10<sup>125</sup> maximum value 
>   -999...(38 9's) x10<sup>125</sup> minimum value
>
> Can be represented to full 38-digit precision (the mantissa).

Simply said, you have 38 significant (decimal) digits.

Given your case, if you use 1 digit *before* the decimal point, you still have 37 digits available at max *just after* the decimal point:

```
NUMBER(38,37)
```

This will cover the range:

```
 -9.9999999999999999999999999999999999999
 +9.9999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

With an [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) of:

```
  0.0000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

This is better in term of precision than [IEEE754 floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) and you will have *exact* representation of decimal numbers.

---

As a side-note, few things to know:

- `NUMBER(x)` is the same thing as `NUMBER(x,0)`. That is a signed decimal *integer*.
- PL/SQL will silently discard numbers after the decimal separator when doing an affectation to a number with a scale lower than the original. see this example:

  ```
  declare
     n1 number(12,1);
     n2 number(11);
  begin
    n1 := 12345678901.2;
    dbms_output.put_line(n1);
    n2 := n1; -- loose precision here !!!
    n1 := n2;
    dbms_output.put_line(n1);
    dbms_output.put_line(n2);
  end;
  ```

  Displaying `12345678901.2`, and then `12345678901` and `12345678901`
- The `CAST` operator will behave exactly same manner:

  ```
  select CAST(12345678901.2 AS NUMBER(11)) FROM DUAL;
  ```

  resulting in `12345678901`.

Comment: my query was regards to variables defined in this manner : v_val number(11) , for this example how would i know how many digits in integral vale and decimal value are possible , given we have defined a 11 digit number?

Comment: `number(11)` is the same thing as `number(11,0)`. That is 11 digits precision, scale 0 -- in other words, this is an [**integer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) in the range `[-99999999999 ; +99999999999]`.